# Wait for EOF when using stdin

Tags: c, file-io

So I am working on something that requires me to let the user type as much as they want in the command window, including new lines, and then after they press CTRL+D (EOF character) I should be able to print out everything that has been typed.

I am able to figure out how to do it every new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  int C;

  C = getc(stdin);

  while(C != EOF)
  {
    putc(C, stdout);
    C = getc(stdin);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I can also only use getc and putc. Eventually I want to let the user type as much as they want and then depending on flags they send with the command I will modify the input they give me using getopt.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to add my question. What I want to be able to do is wait for the user to enter all their input and then print it all back out, not line by line. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: So, exactly what is your question?

Comment: There is no "EOF character" in Unix, what happens is that if the user types ctrl-D into a tty, it handles that as end-of-file to be signalled to the process reading from it.

Comment: Prefer lowercase for variable names.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? A homework? What is the complete problem? What have you tried to do, where are you stuck?

Comment: Note that you see the code echoing every line because of input line buffering. If the user types in some extremely large lines (maybe 4KB or bigger, depending on your libc), or hits `Ctrl+D` in the middle of the line to force an input flush, your code will output text before they finish the line.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to need some way to buffer the user's input (because they might type out a whole novel before hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

Here's an example of how you might do it (note that reading character-by-character is very slow, and using `printf` won't handle embedded NULs so you may want to use `read` and `write` instead in "real" code):

```
size_t bufsize = 1024; // starting size
char *buf = malloc(bufsize);
off_t i = 0;
char c;

while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    buf[i++] = c;
    if(i == bufsize) {
        bufsize *= 2; // double buffer size to avoid constant reallocation
        buf = realloc(buf, bufsize);
        if(!buf) {
            fprintf(stderr, "YOU TYPED TOO MUCH\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

buf[i++] = 0;
printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: Curious: why `off_t i = 0;` and not `size_t i = 0;`?  Minor: no need for `++` in `buf[i++] = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using termios? (termios.h) you can set stdin to non canonical and non echo mode which will let you catch every single key pressed, including control characters

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanon-Example.html